# how to handle item events in checkboxgroup

Tags: java, checkbox, applet, awt, itemlistener

Am not able handle the events of checkboxgroup which act as radio button in applet..
i wanto display a message on applet whenever the checkbox is selected but its not working..
i wanto show a checkbox state with its label in applet,whenever any checkbox is selected then it seems to be display the label and state of checkbox...also the state of the checkbox is not changing... when i click on the checkbox c2 i.e "No" then the state of the checkbox is not changing...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/*<applet code="chg.class" height=500 width=600></applet>*/
public class chg extends Applet implements ItemListener
{
    String msg="Current Selection is:";
    Checkbox c1,c2,c3,c4,c5;
    CheckboxGroup cbg;
    public void init()
    {
        cbg=new CheckboxGroup();
        c1=new Checkbox("YES",cbg,true);
        c2=new Checkbox("No",cbg,false);
        c3=new Checkbox("can",cbg,false);
        c4=new Checkbox("cant",cbg,false);
        c5=new Checkbox("ok",cbg,false);
        add(c1);
        add(c2);
        add(c3);
        add(c4);
        add(c5);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie)
    {
        if(ie.getSource()==c2)
        {
            cbg.setSelectedCheckbox(c2);
        }
        else if(ie.getSource()==c3)
        {
            cbg.setSelectedCheckbox(c3);
        }
        else if(ie.getSource()==c4)
        {
            cbg.setSelectedCheckbox(c4);
        }
        else
        {
            cbg.setSelectedCheckbox(c5);
        }
        repaint();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    { 
        msg+=cbg.getSelectedCheckbox().getLabel();
        g.drawString(msg,6,130);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your item listener to your checkboxes.

```
c1.addItemListener(this);
c2.addItemListener(this);
c3.addItemListener(this);
c4.addItemListener(this);
c5.addItemListener(this);
```

Without adding an itemListener to the boxes, you have no way to get the item events.